# Create new folder with Onedrive API python

Tags: python, python-2.7, onedrive, create-directory

i have problem in creating folder with onedrive API 2.0

here is my code:

```
    _folder = onedrivesdk.Folder()
    _item = onedrivesdk.Item()
    _item.name = new_folder_name
    _item.folder = _folder
    client.item(drive='me', path=location).children.add(_item)
```

it works on windows normally but not on osx

error occur in onedrive sdk children_collection.py

```
entity = Item(json.loads(self.send(entity).content))
```

on this code Item means 'onedrivesdk.model.item.Item'

but sdk define it as global value and return error like this

[error when i create folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljsgg.png)

please help me